# Rain 3D Character Rendering Problems

Tags: rendering

so I made a pose with blender's free 3d character rain. I setup the lights and pressed render but this is what I get...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5D8r.jpg

The second image shows the render mode, and as you can see her legs are visible. Rain comes with a CloudRig menu in which you can mask/hide her arms or legs. But I didn't do that. Does anyone else has this same issue and how can I fix it?
I used cycles render.
Thanks!

Comment: It is preferable, and possibly more likely answered,  if you post images such that  they display in the question.

Comment: Sorry the screenshots are too large that's why I posted a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, there is a mask modifier on the GEO-rain_jeans object, set to only visible render. If you remove the mask modifier or disable it, the jeans will render normally.

Comment: Thank you so much! How didn't I think about checking the mods as well...